# Why are functions like escape, unescape, etc, not methods on the String object?

Tags: javascript, language-design

A string could be seen as the simplest object that can hold and manipulate text, and as such functions that act on strings should not necessarily be lumped in as methods. On the other hand, javascript is primarily a web programming language, and working with URIs is quite a common use for strings in the language; in this case something like `lastName.encodeURIComponent()` would actually be quite useful.

Why things like encodeURIComponent and unescape are functions and not methods on the String object? Is there some CS principle at work here, or was it a subjective choice by one of the designers of the language?

Obviously not every function that operates on a string needs to be in the string object, but where and how do people decide where to draw the line?

Comment: it's like asking why `eval` was also a global and not a method for strings.

Comment: Yes, it is somewhat like asking that. I will amend the question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think those methods are part of JavaScript but are inherited from `window`, which is the global object associated with browsers. Thus, while the functions you listed deal with strings, they're actually closely bound to browser function and thus aren't attached to the `String` prototype. Sources like MDN are sort of murky on this but I'm pretty sure that the original JS spec makes no mention of these methods.

It maybe didn't make much sense, but nowadays it actually is conceivable that someone might want to use JS as the language of an embedded system or something else that has no Internet association. Here, a syntax that included `encodeURIComponent()` would be as out of place as `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 7):

Because they are specific to the browser environment. They don't have a place in the generic String object for the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 1):

Where would you stop. Strings are unbiquitous, by the definition you are using any method that took a string as an argument or returned on should be in the string class.

Equally it would be a reasonable to have Encoding methods that took streams and stream methods that did encoding.

You'd be all over the place quick, or you'd be extending string by delegating to an Encoding class.

Answer (score 1):

The **escape() function encodes** a string.

This function m**akes a string portable**, so it can be **transmitted across any network** to any computer that supports ASCII characters.

This function encodes special characters

Now this functionality is something which is specific to Strings which are URLs in browser based environment, JS as a language is independent of it.

So putting escape,unescape also into String will become useless in non-network/URL related scenarios.

thats why they are **part of Window object**.

You want it in string, you can add  it to String's prototype.